# How to disable core library warnings in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

After installation of CI 3.1, I am getting the below warning message

> Message:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could
>   not be found.

I don't need `imagick` tool for my application. Is there any way to suppress this specific warning? Please help for this fix or suggest any alternate solution for this. I am getting the warning across the entire application.

Comment: you are missing some extensions , go and install imagick extension

Comment: try error_reporting(0); put this in index file, it might be works

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the solution. Let me try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use different patterns to stop that particular error to display

[Different error reporting patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Like:-

```
// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Note:- fatal-error/Syntax-error will shown each time.(you can't hide that)

Comment: Thanks @Alive for your suggestion.